# How to automatically close an alert on JHipster?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, jhipster

I have recently discovered and started to develop in JHipster.

One of the first hurdles I'm facing is to close automatically alerts. So far, I have learned that JHipster uses [Bootstrap UI alerts](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#%2Falert), so I'm trying to adapt the alerts bundled in the [sample project of JHipster](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app), which are shown in the Home when the user tries to log in (the one in green):

[image]

HTML code for alerts was as follows:

```
        <div ng-switch="vm.isAuthenticated()">
            <div class="alert alert-success" ng-switch-when="true" data-translate="home.logged.message" translate-values="{username: '{{vm.account.login}}'}">
                You are logged in as user "{{vm.account.login}}".
            </div>
        </div>
```

Which I modified such as this:

```
            <div class="alert alert-success" ng-switch-when="true" data-translate="home.logged.message" translate-values="{username: '{{vm.account.login}}'}" close="closeAlert()" ng-if="show" dismiss-on-timeout="3000" >
                You are logged in as user "{{vm.account.login}}".
            </div>
```

Javascript file home.controller.js looks like this:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('pruebablogApp')
    .controller('HomeController', HomeController);

HomeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Principal', 'LoginService', '$state', 'AlertService'];

function HomeController ($scope, Principal, LoginService, $state, AlertService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.account = null;
    vm.isAuthenticated = null;
    vm.login = LoginService.open;
    vm.register = register;
    $scope.$on('authenticationSuccess', function() {

        getAccount();
    });

    getAccount();

    function getAccount() {
        Principal.identity().then(function(account, $scope) {
            vm.account = account;
            vm.isAuthenticated = Principal.isAuthenticated;

            if (vm.isAuthenticated){
                $scope.show = true;
                }

        });
    }
    function register () {
        $state.go('register');
    }


    function closeAlert () {
        $scope.show = false;
    }
}
})();
```

This method is not working for me. I've tried other approaches, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32023558/angularjs-bootstrap-alert-dismiss-on-timeout-attribute-doesnt-work) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982806/why-doesnt-dismiss-on-timeout-work-for-ui-bootstraps-alert-directive-after-an) (which should work for button clicks).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

JHipster is using [AlertService](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/webapp/app/components/alert/alert.service.js) as a service in order create the messages type which you want to create (e.g. info, warning, danger etc.) and the message is displayed with the  tag. Have a look at the entities in the sample app to see the tag [jhi-alert](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/webapp/app/entities/operation/operations.html#L3) in action. You just write the tag in the html site and you create in your controller with AlertService the message which you want to create and display.

@Gaël Marziou your answer was more into deep of what is actually happening behind the scene. Can I see it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried this:

_Controller:_

`AlertService.warning("Hi, I'm a warning alert.");`

_View:_

`<jhi-alert></jhi-alert>`

I get this from the elements inspector in Chrome Debug:

`<jhi-alert class="ng-isolate-scope"><div class="alerts" role="alert"><!-- ngRepeat: alert in $ctrl.alerts --></div></jhi-alert>`

Yet no alert is being shown. Something is still wrong.

Comment: try a gulp clean build. If you are editing the other entities of the sample-app, e.g. Label or BankAccount, are you receiving the Alerts? For example when you are creating or editing an entity you should receive a info alert.

Comment: Indeed, I'm receiving those alerts. Tried to rebuild the entire project, no improvement whatsoever. Trying to use AngularJS alerts right now. Thanks for the help!